# How to send commands to 2 or more motors simultaneously using dynamixel_workbench?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Dynamixel XM-430 motors to control my robotic arm. I am a beginner so I don't have much experience on how to use the dynamixel_workbench. I want to send a command to 3 motors at the same time. I hope you can help me with this.
Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288356/how-to-send-commands-to-2-or-more-motors-simultaneously-using-dynamixel_workbench?/) by [Sumil](https://answers.ros.org/users/34606/sumil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

You can make node that has service or topic to command connected Dynamixels.
This code might be help you

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/open_manipulator/blob/master/open_manipulator_dynamixel_ctrl/src/dynamixel_controller.cpp

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0